# Junit Android Settings

Tags: android, junit, junit4, android-espresso

For running the espresso Junit , I want to run the application in offline mode.
and for offline mode i have done following changes.
I have kept all the jsons in the asset folder and from that json i am fetching the data for my application various modules.
I have following queries with my android Project.

Is there any way in gradle , manifest or application class from where i can set the condition that for normal flow app should work on online actual services while for junit run it should run in offline mode.

Second query is that for normal apk , i don't want to include all these jsons which i have kept in my asset folder . How i can achieve same from gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519426/android-apps-which-works-in-online-and-offline-mode) exchange will provide some insight on where to store data (jsons) persistently like you want to do.

Have you explored [productFlavors](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)? I think that will take care of your second query.